# In an enumerate environment, I want one item to have 2 cases and be labelled A2 and A2'

Tags: enumerate

I am using the enumitem package. I have the following code which works fine:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\mathbf{A}\arabic*)]
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Modified second item
\item Third item
\end{enumerate}
```

The modified second item here will be given the label (A3). I would like it have the label (A2') instead. How can I do this?

Comment: What is `\subscript`?

Comment: Sorry, it's a simple custom command that takes 2 arguments and subscripts the first argument with the second, $#1_{#2}$. I will edit the question to remove this since it is unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option. I used `\setlist` to define a starred version of the `\item` command only inside of the `enumerate` environment. The starred version will not step the `enumi` counter, and will place a `'` on the item instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\let\olditem\item
\setlist[enumerate]{
    label=(\textbf{A}\arabic*),
    before=\changeitem,
    after=\let\item\olditem
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\changeitem}{%
    \renewcommand*{\item}{%
        \@ifstar{\starreditem}{\olditem}%
    }%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\starreditem}{%
    \item[(\textbf{A}\arabic{enumi}')]%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item* Modified second item
\item Third item
\item Fourth item
\item* Modified fourth item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```